# PHP to SQL Server without ODBC or MSSQL support

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm in a situation where my Windows hosting has PHP support, but the PHP is not configured to support ODBC or MSSQL.  I can't get them to change that, so I'm wondering if there's a way to connect to SQL Server through other means - maybe including some files that provide the functions that I'd need?

Comment: You could install a service on your SQL server that provides data access to your web application by some other means. Perhaps soap or rest, or a custom web service. The best bet, though, is probably to find a different hostin company.

Comment: I'd be talking your business elsewhere. Sounds like they don't even realy want to be running PHP, which under windows I can understand.

Comment: Flimzy - I don't have access to the SQL Server itself.  Flimzy/Scuzzy - Not a bad suggestion, but I found how to do it in PHP, so I'm going to stick with them.  They're good once I'm situated - just a pain to do anything new (or deal with tech support, who are fairly useless).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving it up here in the hopes that it will make it easier for other people to get around this type of limitation.

Copied here for completeness:

```
<?php 
$db = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); 
$dsn = "DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER={SERVER};UID={USER};PWD={PASS}; DATABASE={DB}";
 $db->Open($dsn); 
$rs = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM table"); 

while (!$rs->EOF) 
{ 
    echo $rs->Fields['column']->Value."<BR>"; 
    $rs->MoveNext(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: link 404 Not Found

Comment: @dewaz Which is why I copied it here, so that we'd still have the code if the link went dead.