# Connect to mssql without mssql support

Tags: php, sql-server, json

Is it possible to connect to a SQL Server without PDO / sqlsvr extensions?
My host does support any SQL Server connections,

i was thinking about a remote page that can do SQL Server stuff and send it to my host, using JSON
no idea if this is possible or not

Comment: You can't connect with mssql_connect?

Comment: can you specify in what way your host does not support mssql connections ? No driver ? What OS ?

Comment: They do not have any support for MSSQL, no PDO, mssql_connect, sqlsvr ... nothing that can connect to a mssql server, only mysql; PS: the run on LINUX

Comment: Found this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643988/php-to-sql-server-without-odbc-or-mssql-support?rq=1 it does not work

Comment: Why you dont look for other hosting that support this feature? basically hosting provider provide connect remotely to your database.

Comment: Well i used to have an hosting with mssql, but i have 4 domains, so thats 4x hosting costs, therefore i switched to another host that has 1 time server costs and unlimited domains on 1 host so ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can write web services which will communicate with mssql server and then transport data on http for your web application for this you have to maintain both services and web application and sure you donot want to, better is to follow douglas suggestion and find a new hosting.

Comment: Ive found that out also, using APIs

Answer (score 0):

You could put a remote page in between which acts as the connection between the MSSQL server and your webserver. But this remote page has to be hosted on another server, so why not move the whole web application to this other server like Douglas Thomas says?