# sqlsrv drivers doesn't appear on a WAMP server phphinfo() after adding the extension entries in the php.ini file

Tags: php, pdo, wampserver

I wanted to setup a database connection from PHP to SQL server 2012.I have a wamp server(64 bit) set up on a windows machine(64 bit) with PHP 5.5.12 and on the same machine I have SQL server 2012 installed.

Extracted sqlsrv drivers from [official_link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

Copied the extracted drivers php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll, `extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` to `php\ext` folder, and then changed the php.ini file to include the extensions

```
extension = php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll; extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll;
```

Now I tried

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
 ?>
```

I see the following information without any SQL server information in it.

[image]

[image]

Don't seem to have configured SQL server connection successfully. Could some one please guide me on what I am missing here.

Comment: Did you restart all services and maybe even rebooted after making the changes? If not, do.

Comment: Yes I restarted all the services.

Comment: Have you also download and installed the `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client` and `Microsoft ODBC Driver 11`. Remember the php extensions do not talk directly to the database, they talk to the Native Client. See the `System Requirements` section on the download page you reference above.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have complete SQL server installed on the same machine, so I already have 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client' installed by default that came with sql server installation. I checked ODBC administrator to confirm.

Comment: Can you try executing the php.exe from a command prompt. It may give you additional error output that you cannot see on the web.

Comment: sorry if im wrong (i dont use mssql) but is this an simple extension or a zend extension?

Comment: You have to compile php from source. with "--with-mssql" option. since pecl does not support any pdo/mssql/sybase extension on windows. http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/

Comment: try non thread safe version of sql driver for php. also if you can try 32bit version of wamp with sql server driver i had a terrible experience with 64bit wamp and mssql ;)

Comment: clear wamp's logs , and restart wamp, read log , it's must contain a error ,that explain why dll not loaded!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64 bit WAMP server was not able to connect using the drivers extension = php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll; extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll;

So, I installed a 32 bit version of the WAMP server and it works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Check the php error log (c:\wamp\logs\php_error.log).
I had the same setup (64bit WAMP/PHP 5.5.12) and same missing sqlsrv reference in phpinfo and I got this error in my log:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - %1 is not a
>   valid Win32 application.  in Unknown on line 0

The solution was to install the 64bit version of the sqlsrv drivers. I found the unofficial 64bit drivers through http://robsphp.blogspot.nl/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

Warning: In my testing I found these 64bit PHP_PDO_SQLSRV extension 10 times slower than when using PHP_PDO_ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

I am visiting this thread and i think this might help full for you and other with the same issue:
[How can I install pdo_sqlsrv on my windows 2008 Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223788/how-can-i-install-pdo-sqlsrv-on-my-windows-2008-server-2008-r2)

The PDO Extension is not the same as the native driver Microsoft is offering. For PDO you must enable

extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
in your php.ini.

> {Normally this file (php_pdo_mssql.dll) should be in your PHP extension-directory (C:...\php\ext). If it's not there you can download PHP from http://windows.php.net/download/ and just take the extension from a package there (take one that correspond with your PHP version of course)}.

Above is taken from [PDO MSSQL Server - Driver not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246007/pdo-mssql-server-driver-not-found) 
read for more details. i have the same issue foe linux and i have saved all the pages thats why i am quoting for you help.

if all above didn't work for you then:

---

On the php.net it is listed that

> On Windows, PDO_ODBC is built into the PHP core by default. It is linked against the Windows ODBC Driver Manager so that PHP can connect to any database cataloged as a System DSN, and is the recommended driver for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server databases.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

You can connect to mssql server using odbc drivers as i have never connect by my self from windows i use to do it through linux using freeTds, following pages might help you

1. http://craigballinger.com/blog/2011/08/usin-php-5-3-with-mssql-pdo-on-windows/
2. [Connect PHP to MSSQL via PDO ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc)
3. [PHP to SQL Server without ODBC or MSSQL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643988/php-to-sql-server-without-odbc-or-mssql-support)