# xampp and mssql sqlsrv connection is not working in 64 bit system

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, 64-bit, sqlsrv

Previously I connect with xammp v3.2.1 to Mssql(sqlsrv) in 32 bit System. But when I mygrate my server to 64 bit system I failed to connect xampp to sqlsrv. I put two dll file in 'C:\xampp\php\ext\' folder.  php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll I download
this two file from

> [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098][1]
>   SQLSRV31.EXE

And I Add following line in php.ini

> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll

I done everything as I done for 32 bit system. But I found following error when I start my xampp in 64 bit system.

> PHP Startup:Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll' - The Specified module
>   could not be found.
>
> PHP Startup:Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll' - The Specified module could
>   not be found.

What should I do now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlsrv drivers doesn't appear on a WAMP server phphinfo() after adding the extension entries in the php.ini file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008506/sqlsrv-drivers-doesnt-appear-on-a-wamp-server-phphinfo-after-adding-the-exten)

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably case of invalid version. Try using 32 bit of PHP extension.

OR follow this step.

1. Download Apache 64 bit from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/
2. Install PHP (NON THREAD SAFE)
3. Add SQLSrv extensions and run apache.